# Phonegap build does not find the assets

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build

I am building my app with the command **phonegap build android** and then i am testing the apk in my phone and i get this errors for all my assets:

```
file:///css/app.min-bb9efaa2.css Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Uncaught ReferenceError: app is not defined
(program):1 exception firing pause event from native index.html
```

I tried to move all the assets to my root but it does not help too.

I have build before and it is not happen to me ever, What is the problem?

[image: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND]

Comment: Can you show the lines of code where you import that CSS file?

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.min-bb9efaa2.css"/>

Comment: I see two possible errors in your error message #1 Did you mean to use file:// ? or http:// #2 if you plan on using the file:/// you need three slashes.

Comment: Where i need three slashes?

Comment: I am seeing this issue too, any help would be appreciated.